# Sufficient Requirement to be a Galois Extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Related to my last question:

In Silverman and Tate, *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*, there is the following proposition.

> **Proposition 6.5.** Let $E$ be an elliptic curve given by a Weierstrass equation $$E:y^2=x^3+ax^2+bx+c, \quad a,b,c \in \mathbb{Q}.$$
>   (a) Let $P=(x_1,y_1)$ be a point of order dividing $n$. Then $x_1$ and $y_1$ are algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$.
>
> (b) Let $$E[n]=\{(x_1,y_1) , \cdot \cdot \cdot , (x_m,y_m) , \mathcal{O} \}$$be the complete set of points of $E(\mathbb{C})$ of order dividing $n$. Let $$K=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,y_1 , \cdot \cdot \cdot , x_m,y_m )$$ be the field generated by the coordinates of all of the points in $E[n]$. Then $K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

So, (a) proves that the extension  $K=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,y_1 , \cdot \cdot \cdot , x_m,y_m )$ is an algebraic extension.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_extension) says

> A Galois extension is an algebraic field extension $E/F$ that is normal and separable; or equivalently, $E/F$ is algebraic, and the field fixed by the automorphism group Aut$(E/F)$ is precisely the base field $F$.

Since all embeddings of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{C}$ fix $\mathbb{Q}$, can we immediately conclude that $K=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,y_1 , \cdot \cdot \cdot , x_m,y_m )$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$? (The proof in the text shows that all field homomorphisms $\sigma: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ are automorphisms of $K$, and concludes this shows that $K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes the multiplication by $n$ map $(a,b)\mapsto [n](a,b)$ is given by a pair of rational functions in $a,b$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$ thus for $\sigma \in Gal(\overline{\Bbb{Q}}/\Bbb{Q})$ then $$[n](x_j,y_j) =O\implies \text{ the denominator vanishes} \implies [n](\sigma(x_j),\sigma(y_j))=O$$ ie. $(\sigma(x_j),\sigma(y_j))\in K^2$ and $\sigma(K)\subset K$ ie. $K/\Bbb{Q}$ is normal, in characteristic $0$ it is separable thus it is Galois. Moreover $\sigma$ commutes with the addition of $E$ so that $Gal(K/\Bbb{Q})$ is a subgroup of $Aut(E[n])$.

Comment: So it's still necessary to check the $\sigma(K)=K$. . . ? (I know how, I don't understand if/why it's necessary if we know it has to fix $\mathbb{Q}$ as per the wiki definition)

Comment: $\sigma(K)\subset K$ implies $K$ contains all the conjugates of its elements, thus it is Galois and $\sigma(K)= K$. To avoid the $O=\infty$ and vanishing denomiantor stuffs look at the projective curve

Comment: I'm still confused. In general, which conditions are sufficient? i.e., is it necessary that 1) the extension is algebraic, 2) the automorphism group fixes the base field, 3) all homomorphisms of the extension are automorphisms. Or are 1) and 3) (or 1 and 2) suffiicient?

Comment: There are two definitions of $K/\Bbb{Q}$ Galois : finite extension and $\forall \sigma,\sigma(K)=K$, and $\Bbb{Q}$ is the subfield of $K$ fixed by a finite subgroup of $Aut(K)$. The fundamental theorem of Galois theory is that they are equivalent. The fixed subfield is the one giving the minimal polynomials and the subextensions.

Comment: One last question: We know that $K=\mathbb{Q}(x_1,y_1 , \cdot \cdot \cdot , x_m,y_m )$ is a finite extension because all $x_i,y_i$ are agebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ and there are finitely many $x_i,y_i$. Is this correct? (If they were not algebraic, then it wouldn't be a finite extension?)

Comment: Yes. They are algebraic because with $u_n/v_n$ the rational function (in $x,y$) giving the first component of the multiplication by $n$ then $\frac{u_n(x,\sqrt{x^3+ax+b})}{v_n(x,\sqrt{x^3+ax+b})}= \infty$ means $v_n(x,\sqrt{x^3+ax+b})v_n(x,-\sqrt{x^3+ax+b})=0$ which is a polynomial equation in $x$.